# How to edit WordPress page's html code

Tags: html, wordpress

I can't get editable html code behind the page. I want to make some changes to the page. Web site is hosted in the remote server. Someone assigned this task. There is empty editor when open edit page as below image.

[image]

Also I added plugin and actived it but can't get the result.

Comment: You'll need to edit the page template itself. No way you are going to edit html or php code from there

Comment: @PieterGoosen Where I can find it. Is there any directory by convention to store pages like this?

Comment: In your wordpress folder on the server, there will be a folder called wp-content, inside that will be folder called themes, inside that will be a folder with the name of your theme, inside that will be your template files and folders. Looking at your pic, you need to open and edit page.php. one note, never edit online files blindly, one little mistake will break you site. First test all code off line (if you don't have a local test install, get yourself one now) before making changes online. And never ever use the back end editors to edit template files. As I said, one mistake breaks your site

Answer (score 7):

The picture you posted is of the WYSIWYG editor, which is only for adding content to the page.

If you want to edit the layout of the page itself you have 2 options -

Minor page edits to appear across all pages on the site - Go to Appearance -> editor -> page.php and then edit the code to suite your needs.

Large page edits to appear on one or two pages -

- Get access to the files
- Duplicate page.php with a different name
- Edit code

When you go to add a new page you should have an option to pick a page template. Choose the page template you just created.

Comment: Never ever use the back end editor. One little teeny weeny mistake will break your site

Comment: I always ensure I have a backup and access to the site through FTP just incase, i guess it's just each to their own style of working

Comment: It is still bad practice and a lot of headaches. It is also unprofessional if you break a live site and clients are busy browsing the site

Comment: @Pieter is correct - making changes via Appearance --> Editor is a well established no-no.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly what you are doing, you can use Chrome "Inspect" feature, and change the HTML of the content inside the WordPress WYSIWYG Editor. After injecting your HTML, click Preview or Publish and your changes will be saved correctly.

Comment: funny approach :)

Comment: Thanks for the last resort. Unfortunately didn't work for me, as the problematic part I'm trying to fix is in the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 5.5.3, you should be able to click the three dots on the top right, then select *Code editor*. Alternatively, press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M`.