# Edit code of page on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to edit the HTML code of my Wordpress page. Exactly, I want to create a page, not posts, in my [Wordpress page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages), where I want expose my CV and insert my photo which [will changes when I pass the mouse above of it](https://www.codesyntax.com/eu/bloga/author/lfernandez).

I tried to search something about this and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338249/how-to-edit-wordpress-pages-html-code). In this reference, the writer speaks about the code modification, but isn't my particular case.

When I try to edit the code in the Wordpress page, I can't use some codes. For example: `<a>`, `<div>` ...

I want to use something like this:

```
<div class="authorimage">
   <a href="https://www.codesyntax.com/eu/bloga/author/lfernandez">
       <img class="mainimage" src="https://www.codesyntax.com/lfernandez.jpg" alt="Luistxo Fernandez" title="Luistxo Fernandez">
       <img class="hoverimage" src="https://www.codesyntax.com/lfernandezhover.jpg" alt="Luistxo Fernandez" title="Luistxo Fernandez">
   </a>

</div>
```

But in the published page the following appears:

```
 <img class="mainimage" src="https://www.codesyntax.com/lfernandez.jpg" alt="Luistxo Fernandez" title="Luistxo Fernandez">
 <img class="hoverimage" src="https://www.codesyntax.com/lfernandezhover.jpg" alt="Luistxo Fernandez" title="Luistxo Fernandez">
```

I need use this code for my purpose. what can i do to fix this problem?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below link, this should work,

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-introduction/adding-html-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Log into your WordPress dashboard and create a new page. On that new page you can insert your CV and photo and then publish it.

Comment: Yes, i know it, but when I create a new page and I try to insert HTML code, I am not allowed to insert codes like `<a>` .

Comment: Please try to be specific about what you are trying to insert and what error message do you see. Do you have the privileges to publish?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "text" mode in the text editor (instead of "visual mode") when you use the text editor to create a new page. There you can write HTML code.

Or, in "visual mode", just use select the part of the text on which you want to put the link and clock on the link symbol (the chain icon) above the text editor.

Comment: I use <a> but my purpose isn't create a link, I want to insert a dynamic photo as shown in the message example.

Comment: whatever you mean by "dynamic photo" etc.: As I wrote, you can use the text mode in the editor to write HTML code