# How to edit WordPress v4.9.5 page's html code

Tags: html, wordpress, editor, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to make some changes to the page. So I tried following this 
[How to edit WordPress page's html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338249/how-to-edit-wordpress-pages-html-code) but this is a different Wordpress version and the Editor tab is missing. I can't get editable html code behind the page.

Here's a sample image:
[image: Study Wizards added page]

My task is to change the Image goes here to an actual image. The style of the page is similar to other pages but they only differ with the content and the image.

In Wordpress, I go to the Pages then edit but there's only codes for the contents.

Here's an image:
[image: Wordpress screenshot]

I have to replace the left box to an actual image. And as you can see in the Appearance Tab there's no Editor Tab. How can I edit the image part and do that to the new version of Wordpress? Please help me with this. Sorry I'm new in Wordpress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- Appearance Tab --> Editor --> Edit theme so if you want edit it can use FTP hosting.
- [File Manager — WordPress Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager/) or http://www.bestplugins.com/cms/wordpress-ftp-plugin.html