# Is there a way to find and edit a specific piece of html in wordpress?

Tags: html

Is there a way to find and edit a specific piece of html in wordpress?

I can find the html in view-source, but can't locate it in backend files.

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi, you can see about wordpress plugin : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit WordPress page's html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338249/how-to-edit-wordpress-pages-html-code)